# DetailViewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath - iOS iPhone 5 Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to load a DetailViewController when I tap on the first cell of a table in MasterViewController (num == 0). This is the code I have now:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSInteger num = indexPath.row;
    if(num == 0){
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.viewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Detail" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    } else if(num == 1){

    }

}
```

But this is giving a Thread 1: SIGABRT. How should I load the DetailViewController called Detail in the storyboard?

Comment: Can we see a crash log?

Comment: Why are you creating a new window? Do you have a navigation controller?

Comment: I just want to load different DetailViewControllers when I tap different cells in the table. Can you provide me with the right code?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times on SO, so do some searching. You can also see how to do this in Apple's documentation in the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS".

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller? A segue? You need to give details

Comment: What on earth are you doing with the window and the window's root view controller. I've looked at your past questions are you really are clueless and in a pickle. I don't say this to sound rude, but you really ought to take some time out and slow down and read a basic iOS book. You're all over the place at the moment and posting questions on here isn't helping, probably making things worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't allocate a new UIWindow object. 
Just load the DetailViewController from nib, as you do. 
And then push it, assuming your current view controller is controlled by a navigation controller already.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```